# Selenium Python script won't find an XPATH that is present

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, automation

I'm trying to write a script that opens my staging URL and clicks/sendskeys through a flow.

I'm getting stuck with errors that I think indicate the element isn't present ( Message: unknown error: result.webdriverValue.value list is missing or empty in Runtime.callFunctionOn response)

I'm a noob just tring to improve their life, so if anyone can diagnose my script I would greatly appreciate it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time


    chrome_driver_path = r"C:\Users\tyler\Downloads\chromedriver-win64\chromedriver-win64\chromedriver.exe"
    
    service = Service(executable_path=chrome_driver_path)
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
    
    try:
        driver.get("my-staging-URL")
        time.sleep(10)
    
        driver.find_element("xpath", '/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/header/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/button[2]/div/div/p').click()
        
        time.sleep(5)
      
    #driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=selenium+xpath")
    
        
    
    except NoSuchElementException as e:
        print("Element not found:", e)
    
    input("Press any key to close the browser")
```

For more context, when I use this xpath in a tool like Katalon recorder it works fine.

Comment: Do you have XPATH working on anything?

Comment: I just tried on google's input field and it appears to not be working

Comment: If you are new to Selenium and just getting started I might suggest looking at Playwright.

Comment: Might be sound advice but I'm going to stick out learning selenium, I see one issue that  I made. xpath should be By.XPATH.

Comment: You might want to review your find_element method, and be sure you're using the correct Xpath (right-click, inspect, and be sure the element is completely highlighted in blue)

Comment: Without a link to the page or at least the relevant and surrounding HTML, we aren't going to be able to give you a better locator. Absolute XPaths (XPaths that start at `/html`), XPaths that have many levels, and XPaths that contain indices (e.g. `/div[1]`) are going to be very brittle (break with even minor changes to the page) and should be avoided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not the right expression in selenium4.1......
`driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/header/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/button[2]/div/div/p').click()`